# How to extract values from list of dictionaries based upon another list values?

Tags: python

I have a lists of dictionaries

```
user_details = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'abc.kbc@gmail.com'}, {'id': 12, 'name': 'xyz@gmail.com'}]
```

and I have another list

```
user_emails = ['abc.kbc@gmail.com', 'xyz@gmail.com']
```

I want to extract ids based upon the matching email ids from another list. How can I do that in python?

Expected result:

```
[1,12]
```

What I have tried is

```
[user['id'] for user in user_details if user_details['name'] in user_emails]
```

But it gives below error:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `[user['id'] for user in user_details if user['name'] in user_emails]`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the `user_emails` list, and then find the associated id:

```py
output = []
# loop over user_emails
for mail in user_emails:
    # loop over user_details
    for detail in user_details:
        # check if name matches
        if detail.get("name") == mail:
            # append id to output
            output.append(detail.get("id"))
            break
print(output) # [1, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
return_list = []

for email in user_emails:
   for user in user_details:
       if user["name"] == email:
           return_list.append(user["id"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a more straightforward function to do this, but here's what I'd do:

```
ids = list()
#gp through the list of users
for user in user_details:
  # if the user's email is in the list of emails
  if user["name"] in user_emails:
    # append the list of ids
    ids.append(user["id"])
```

By the end, the result will be `ids = [1,12]` This seems to be the less time-consuming way because it uses a single for loop.

Comment: "This seems to be the less time-consuming way because it uses a single for loop." Hiding a for loop behind `in` doesn't make code any faster. You still iterating over each element of `user_details` during each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Yeah, I should've written "explicit loop" but I'm not sure how `in` behaves or if its implementation is faster.